# Duplicate field 'Status' when I try to run 'pio status'

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, predictionio

When ever I do `pio status` I get the following error

```
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting PredictionIO...
[INFO] [Management$] PredictionIO 0.13.0 is installed at /Users/prvns/tools/PredictionIO-0.13.0
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting Apache Spark...
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark is installed at /Users/prvns/tools/PredictionIO-0.13.0/vendors/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
[INFO] [Management$] Apache Spark 2.3.1 detected (meets minimum requirement of 1.6.3)
[INFO] [Management$] Inspecting storage backend connections...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Meta Data Backend (Source: ELASTICSEARCH)...
[ERROR] [Management$] Unable to connect to all storage backends successfully.
The following shows the error message from the storage backend.

PUT http://localhost:9200/pio_meta/_mapping/engine_instances: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"Failed to parse content to map","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Duplicate field 'status'\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.compress.DeflateCompressor$1@6b496f00; line: 1, column: 462]"}},"status":400} (org.apache.predictionio.shaded.org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException)

Dumping configuration of initialized storage backend sources.
Please make sure they are correct.

Source Name: ELASTICSEARCH; Type: elasticsearch; Configuration: HOME -> /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.2.4/, HOSTS -> localhost, PORTS -> 9200, SCHEMES -> http, TYPE -> elasticsearch
```

My `pio-env.sh` looks like

```
SPARK_HOME=$PIO_HOME/vendors/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
POSTGRES_JDBC_DRIVER=$PIO_HOME/lib/postgresql-42.0.0.jar
MYSQL_JDBC_DRIVER=$PIO_HOME/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41.jar
PIO_FS_BASEDIR=$HOME/.pio_store
PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/engines
PIO_FS_TMPDIR=$PIO_FS_BASEDIR/tmp
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model
PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_PORTS=9200
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEMES=http
PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/6.2.4/
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using `ElasticSearch 6.x`. I replaced it with `ElasticSearch 5.x` and it worked.